# MySQL only show unique changes to column

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure if this is an easy query or not but for some reason can't figure it out...

I have this record of status changes in descending order (oldest to newest):

```
  Name       Status               Time
   A          Up        2018-06-21 00:07:00.000000
   A          Up        2018-05-21 00:07:00.000000
   A         Down       2018-04-21 00:07:00.000000
   A         Down       2018-03-21 00:07:00.000000
   A          Up        2018-02-21 00:07:00.000000
   A         Down       2018-01-21 00:07:00.000000
```

But I only want to return **unique** changes to the `Status` column, thus giving me a list of times the status was changed. So the answer would be as so:

```
  Name       Status               Time
   A          Up        2018-05-21 00:07:00.000000
   A         Down       2018-03-21 00:07:00.000000
   A          Up        2018-02-21 00:07:00.000000
   A         Down       2018-01-21 00:07:00.000000
```

Notice how the result returns the entries from March and May, not April and June, since those were the times that the status changed from a different state.

My query is currently doing some joining so I'm also not sure how/where to fit that in to the query:

```
SELECT
      Instrument.Name AS Name,
      Status.Name AS Status,
      Operation.Time AS Time,
FROM Operation
      INNER JOIN Instrument ON Instrument.Id = Operation.InstrumentId
      INNER JOIN Status ON Status.Id = Operation.StatusId
WHERE Instrument.Name = ?;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want `lag()` and to select from that.  Let me assume that you are pre-v8 of MySQL.

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.status
              from t t2
              where t2.time < t.time
              order by t2.time desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status;
```

In newer versions of MySQL, you can simply do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (order by time) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! (fyi I'm on MySQL 5.7) I'm trying this now but running in to some issues since my query is also doing some other joining (although I didn't think that'd matter to the overall solution) I'll update the question to add more details.

Comment: Just updated the question. I tried using my query in place of the second `select t.*` you wrote, but doesn't seem like that's the way to do it... I'm assuming the 3rd select should stay as is to specify the columns i'm filtering for?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little generic try with the outer query running row by row matching the subquery result via `groups` reason being the output is the way rows are not in a way sorted someway. Can check if this works for you.

```
      SELECT
      Instrument.Name AS Name,
      DISTINCT(Status.Name) AS Status,
      Operation.Time AS Time,
FROM Operation
      INNER JOIN Instrument ON Instrument.Id = Operation.InstrumentId
      INNER JOIN Status ON Status.Id = Operation.StatusId
WHERE ( Name,
      Status,
      Time ) 
      IN
   (SELECT
      Instrument.Name AS Name1,
      Status.Name AS Status1,
      Operation.Time AS Time1,
FROM Operation
      INNER JOIN Instrument ON Instrument.Id = Operation.InstrumentId
      INNER JOIN Status ON Status.Id = Operation.StatusId
     group by NAME1, Status1 having Time1=min(Time1)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach uses a pseudo temporary table (cannot use an actual temporary table since MySql will not allow multiple subqueries to be issued against one) that is the original table with a "row number" appended to it as the primary key:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
create table temp as
  SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS row_num, t.* FROM t order by time;
ALTER TABLE temp ADD PRIMARY KEY (row_num);
```

Then the query becomes simply:

```
select name, status, time from temp temp1
    where temp1.row_num = 1
    or temp1.status <>
       (select temp2.status from temp temp2 where temp2.row_num = temp1.row_num - 1);

drop table temp; /* no longer need this table */
```